# Is it possible to Host a WPF Page in HwndHost?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, uwp, composition

**First of all this might feel as a stupid Question (You could have loaded WPF content directly in a WPF window), but actually read the full description to know why I need this.**

I am developing a C# WPF Application to Emulate Windows Acrylic Blur Effect. I am using sample code from here: [Win32 Composition Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/AcrylicEffect).

With this code I was able to create the acrylic blur on an `HwndHost` or Directly on the Window. But this causes the Windows Aerospace Issue which means all the controls I draw on the window will appear under the AcrylicBlur (Blurred). Like this one :

[image: Acrylic Issue]

*Acrylic Content Overlapping My WPF Button*

So I decided to create a window with acrylic effect and create a `HwndHost` as the child of that window so that I could overlap the WPF Content on top of the Acrylic Blur so that the WPF Controls Won't Get Blurred Out.

### Solution That Might Work

There is One more Concept that I can try out, is to create two windows one with the acrylic and one with the WPF and share there `WM_POSITIONCHANGED` Message for both window which cause the windows to move and resize equally. But this have several issues.

Comment: How would that fix the airspace issue? The only way is to be fully integrated with windows composition, which you can't do with WPF. You could have a look at o WinUI3.

Comment: Win UI3 Doesnot Support Acylic  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/

Comment: Check the platform issues, it supports in app acrylic but not the window acrylic

Comment: It can solve the aerospace issue since i am not passing any events to the acrylic window, overlapping a new window does not create much problem. The official windows composition samples use HWND Host  to Hold the acrylic i am trying to do the opposite and make the HWND Host to hold the WPF Content. so that it could overlap the acrylic. The  Solution that i mentioned there already works but i think HWND Host is way more better than a top level window

Comment: @SimonMourier, you were right it won't solve the issue. i found a way to host WPF Page into a HwndSource instead of HwndHost. but what ever i do the acrylic effect is overlapping the content. so left with no choice, i must go with seperate window solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a way to Host WPF Page, instead of using HwndHost i used HwndSource.

```
HwndSourceParameters param = new HwndSourceParameters("Host");
param.PositionX = 10;
param.PositionY = 10;
param.Width = 500;
param.Height = 500;
param.ExtendedWindowStyle +=0x00200000;  //This style creates a transparent window
param.WindowStyle = 0x10000000;
    
HwndSource src = new HwndSource(param);
src.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
src.CompositionTarget.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
src.RootVisual = new Page1(); //Your Page Here
```

Comment: But This could never be used to solve aero space issue. just posted the answer so it would be helpful for someone else